# Match evething inside PHP comment block using RegExr

Tags: php, regex, matching

I'm struggling to mach everything inside a PHP comment block using RegExr.

i.e.

```
/**
 * MATCH EVETHING HERE
 */
```

So basically, I want to match everything starting straight after `/**` and ending straight before `*/`.

Can someone please provide me with the appropriate RegExr for that.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: solved, its `/\/\/*/*(.*?)*//s`

Comment: If this a DocBlock, e.g. if it is written before a function or method, you can use the Reflection API to fetch it.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('~/**(.*?)*/~ims', $from, $to); 

foreach($to[1] as $contents){
    //$contents contain comment (without /** */) 
}
```

Comment: Thats for your help buddy! but thats not quite what I was looking for, see, I want to match everything inside the comment block as **one** string. One of my followers on twitter gave me this and worked like a charm `/\/\/*/*(.*?)*//s`. Thanks again :).

Comment: @Taha: echo $contents."<br>"; will do the stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the comment of an class you can use the reflector mechanisms of PHP using the [`ReflectionClass::getDocComment()`](http://www.php.net/manual/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php) method.

Example class file:

```
/** 
* A test class
*
* @param  foo bar
* @return baz
*/
class TestClass { }
```

Reflection class usage:

```
$rc = new ReflectionClass('TestClass');
var_dump($rc->getDocComment())
```

Outputs:

```
string(55) "/** 
* A test class
*
* @param  foo bar
* @return baz
*/"
```

**Hint:**
On the ReflectionClass Manual page there is [a good comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php#96431) mentioning this reg exp:

```
    $expr = "/((?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:\/\/.*))/";
```